# How to store the output of meshgrid in a loop by matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, store

By the following code in Matlab, just the output of e = 1 will be stored in the variable eZ.
How can I store all the output of the e loop?

```
x = -pi:pi:pi;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,x);

Z = X.^2+Y.^2;

for e = -1:2:1

    eZ = e-Z

end
```

Thanks in advance,
Mahroo

Comment: How do you want them stored? As a 3rd dimension in an array? As separate arrays in a cell array?

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
for e = -1:2:1

    eZ = e-Z

end
```

Your variable `eZ` gets overriden at each iteration in the loop. If you want to save all your values, you are gonna need your variable `eZ` to be a 3D matrix, and at each iteration in the loop, you are gonna save the data in a "slice" of this matrix:

```
%% How to store....
x = -pi:pi:pi;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,x);

Z = X.^2+Y.^2;

[sz1,sz2] = size(Z);

% Initialize eZ
eZ = zeros(sz1,sz2,length(-1:2:1));

% Counter to know at which "slice" to store your variable
Cnt = 0;

for e = -1:2:1

    Cnt = Cnt + 1;
    
    eZ(:,:,Cnt) = e-Z;

end
```

Note that you can also get the same result by using [Implicit expansion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/generate-code-with-implicit-expansion-enabled.html):

```
e_resh = reshape(-1:2:1,1,1,[]);

eZ_v2 = e-Z;
```